# How does the android OS determine a SensorEvent's accuracy?

Tags: android, sensors

There is a method in the `android.hardware.SensorEventListener` interface called

> void onSensorChanged(android.hardware.SensorEvent sensorEvent)

This method gets called on a registered listener by one of the operating system's threads, whenever it detects that a sensor reading has updated values. The underlying data structure, `SensorEvent` has an field called `SensorEvent#accuracy` which is used to declare the accuracy of the aforementioned event and is one of `Sensor.SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_HIGH`, `Sensor.SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_LOW`, `Sensor.SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_MEDIUM` or `SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE`.

Now, what I really want to know is how the operating system can tell to what degree a sensor event is accurate.

Does it rely on the physical sensor chip to provide it with accuracy information and if so, how can the chip discern a reading's accuracy ?